# Error in finding classpath for CassandraAdminCredentials when using Apache Ignite xml via Scala/Spark

Tags: xml, scala, sbt, ignite

Is there a specific sbt dependency that is required for the following beans that are written out in the Apache Ignite example:

`<bean id="cassandraAdminCredentials" class="org.apache.ignite.tests.utils.CassandraAdminCredentials"/>
    <bean id="cassandraRegularCredentials" class="org.apache.ignite.tests.utils.CassandraRegularCredentials"/>`

Or are there other ways to go about solving this issue?

sbt error response:
`java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.ignite.tests.utils.CassandraAdminCredentials`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As their name implies those are test classes which are only published as test artifacts, not supposed to be used.

I guess you will have to use `org.apache.ignite.cache.store.cassandra.datasource.PlainCredentials`.

I will check examples to see if they need to be corrected.